# MIPS instruction modulo

Tags: mips, modulo

```
b = a % 16

a --> $s0
b --> $s1
```

**Answer: `$s1, $s0, 0xF`**

```
#0xF= 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111
```

When I convert it to decimal, it is 15.

I am not too sure why it is 15?

Comment: this is purely a math question and not related to MIPS in any way

Comment: Sorry about that! Cause it was under my MIPS lecture so i thought so. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder when dividing any number by `b` is in the range [0, b-1]. So modulo 16 returns a maximum value of 15

To get modulo 2<sup>N</sup> of any number we take the last N bits of it, because any higher bit at position M with M > N represents a value 2<sup>M</sup> which is divisible by 2<sup>N</sup>. The mask to get N bits is **2<sup>N</sup> - 1**. That means a % 16 = a & 0xF = a & 15

Answer (score 1):

When using the MIPS command div for division, the result is stored in the register lo while the modolo is stored in the register hi.

So if a=$s0, b=$s1 and $t0 = 16 you could use

```
div $s0,$t0
mfhi $s1
```

for b=a%16